# Woocommerce Hook v 4.6.1 - How to output one or more Strings with echo

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

please

this is the Hook inside the functions.php file.

how can i output this script below please?

because of that line, i got a error message in the debug.log file

```
line 1767 <?php echo do_shortcode('[addthis tool="addthis_inline_share_toolbox_r1xt"]'); ?>
```

Error Message: **debug.log**

```
[22-Oct-2020 17:22:28 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'tool' (T_STRING), expecting ']' in C:\xampppserver2\htdocs\mrdigital\wp-content\themes\astra-child\functions.php on line 1767
```

I'm using the **single quotes** in the whole Script, so this is the conflict reason:

Gratitude!

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'box_sharing_social_icons', 10, 1 );

function box_sharing_social_icons($order) {

    echo '
        <!-- start box -->
        <div class="share_pattern">
            <h2 class="woocommerce-column__title">Sharing</h2>
            <div class="content_share d-flex">
            <div><p>Explanation<br>
                Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget tortor risus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus.</p>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[addthis tool="addthis_inline_share_toolbox_r1xt"]'); ?>

                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Proin eget tortor risus. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php echo str_repeat("<br>", 1) ?>
    <!-- end box -->
    ';       

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you didn't post it, you're almost assuredly experiencing a syntax error... reference the actual error notice to know what problem you are running in to. Line numbers aren't that helpful to us for diagnosing the issue since the line numbers in your snippet aren't the same.

You're in the middle of echoing out string text, so you don't open a `<?php` tag. Removing the two instances where you open and close the PHP tags would probably work. Or since you are directly writing out HTML, I'd probably close the pho tags... print the HTML... then open the PHP tags again for the shortcode reference.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'box_sharing_social_icons', 10, 1 );
function box_sharing_social_icons($order) { ?>

        <!-- start box -->
        <div class="share_pattern">
            <h2 class="woocommerce-column__title">Compartilhar</h2>
            <div class="content_share d-flex">
            <div><p>Explicação<br>
                Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget tortor risus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus.</p>
                <div class="text-center">
                  <?php echo do_shortcode('[addthis tool="addthis_inline_share_toolbox_r1xt"]'); ?>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Proin eget tortor risus. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- end box -->
<?php     
}
```

Comment: hello @helgatheviking,

thank you so much for the huge Help and the great explanation!

The script is up and running! **Gratitude!!**